# Better way to load dropdown list from comma separated string

Tags: jquery

I have a string of comma separated values. I need to split the string and load each entry in a `dropdown`. I have following code that does this job.

Is there any better code that reduces the number of lines without using any other library?

**CODE**

```
               //Remove existing entries from dropdown
                $('.ddlASN').empty();

                //Split string to array
                var arr = result.split(',');

                //Loop through array
                for(var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++)
                {

                    //Add ddl options - text and value
                    $('.ddlASN').append($('<option></option>').val(arr[i]).html(arr[i]));
          }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify it to:

```
$.each(result.split(','), function(i, e) {
    $('.ddlASN').append($('<option>', { value: e, text: e }));
});
```

Comment: You should still use `$('.ddlASN').empty()` to clear the existing ones.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fancy shmancy solution:

```
$('.ddlASN').html($.map(result.split(','), function(item) {
  $('<option></option>').val(item).html(item)[0].outerHtml()
}).join(''));
```

It replaces the html content of the select tag so there is no need to clear the content first.

See in [action](http://jsfiddle.net/86PbF/)

Bottom line, I would rather use the simple and clear solution in the question rather than my own answer which was just for the challenge.